# What is the best process flow when accessing API with valid or invalid access token?

Tags: authentication, identityserver4, access-token, refresh-token

I have tried to google this, but can't get the answer I'm looking for. I'm quite new to authentication so, maybe I'm not searching for the correct terms.

I have the following setup:

I have an IdentityServer4 to authenticate users/clients.
I have a client mobile app.
I have a API protected by IdentityServer.

I am trying to figure out the best way to implement the program flow when taking user authentication into account, considering all the scenarios that can take place.  Can anyone recommend a the flow of events for the best user experience please?

So the user logs in to IdentityServer and I get an authorization code back (expires in 5 mins). I also have a refresh token, which I can save away securely.

I can access the API in the next 5 mins with the access token.

Now, say I want to query the API again in a few minutes, how do I detect that this access token is still valid?  Is the best way to simply try and access the API and if you get a 401 go back to IdentityServer with the refresh token? or do you keep an internal note of the expiry time and go get the refresh without bouncing off the API?  I'm just looking for guidance on this as I can't find any discussions or posts on the process flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use your **authorization code** to get an access token. The **access token** default lifetime is 1 hour. If the token now has one hour lifetime, then you could in code after (for example) 55 minutes use the **refresh token** to get a new access token.

Or as you say, if you get a 401 back, try to use the refresh token to get a new one.

You can also **programmatically** pass the access token to the **token introspection** endpoint to check if a token is still **valid**.